# Should I precompress my static files before serving them with a web server?

Tags: nginx, static, gzip

I see that nginx has an option to send pregzipped files without compressing them on the fly.

I have a list of static css and javascript files that I can gzip and put in a respective folder to be served with `ngx_http_gzip_static_module` module.

I find it more effective to have these files gzipped when server is deployed, than on each request.

So, should I precompress them to gain speed or won't this add significant resources economy and I shouldn't bother about it?